# Proper way to configure Kestrel on AspNetCore with configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

So I've been messing around with AspNetCore for a while now. And there is one thing I'm having a hard time understanding.

I want to use a configuration file when loading the application for basic setup but I'm finding little to know documentation on how to use the IConfiguration interface with certain objects like `KestrelOptions.Configure(IConfiguration configuration)`

Where do I find what values I can put in the config file? I've searched quite a bit on learn.microsoft.com with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's a list of [Host Configuration Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#host-configuration-values).

I have the JSON:

```
{
    "urls": "http://*:8284",
}
```

When you use the configuration:

```
var webHostBuilder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
.UseConfiguration(config)
```

It corresponds to [`Key: urls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1#server-urls).  Kestrel uses some of the same values.

Kestrel specific configuration is loaded from `"Kestrel"` section by default.  [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1#endpoint-configuration):

```
{
"Kestrel": {
"EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
    "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
```

Using [strongly-typed options](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/09/strongly-typed-configuration-in-asp-net-core-without-ioptionst/) is another approach that is a bit more explicit.